# How can I limit the number of characters output at a time for image to ASCII converter to output in discord with 2000 character limit per message

Tags: python, discord.py, ascii-art, image-conversion

I have an image to ASCII converter working with a discord bot so people can send it an image, it downloads it and converts it to ASCII and sends it back to them, but since Discord limits messages to 2000 characters each it often gets stuck making images of reasonable size.

I used [this](https://youtu.be/v_raWlX7tZY) tutorial to convert the images and I believe this line of code:

```
asciiImage = "\n".join(newImageData[i:(i + newWidth)] for i in range(0, pixelCount, newWidth))
```

is the one I need to fix, I believe it connects each line of the image to a newline character based off the newWidth variable, which you enter when you give it the image. How would I limit it to only add lines until the next line would go over 2000, output that (or add it to a list) and then repeat until it has finished the image?

Sorry if this is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over it in a for-loop and keep track of the current size of the string. In case adding the next line would make it too big, send it, reset the string and keep going.

Afterwards, if necessary, send the last part of the string (which won't get sent automatically in the for-loop).

**Note**: This example below assumes you have a `channel` to send the message to, replace it with `ctx` or `user` or whatever your intentions are. `Channel` is just for the sake of this example.

```py
# Entire ascii image as a list of lines (not joined into one string)
asciiImage = list(newImageData[i:(i + newWidth)] for i in range(0, pixelCount, newWidth))

# String to send
send_str = ""

for line in asciiImage:
    # Adding this line would make it too big
    # 1998 = 2000 - 2, 2 characters for the newline (\n) that would be added
    if len(send_str) + len(line) > 1998:
        # Send the current part
        await channel.send(send_str)
        # Reset the string
        send_str = ""

    # Add this line to the string
    send_str += line + "\n"
    
# Send the remaining part
if send_str:
    await channel.send(send_str)
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you, but it no longer adds the newline characters, as before, is this easy to re-add?

Edit: I figured it out, it was really simple, just  had to add on a newline at line 16 of the code, thanks so much.

Comment: Ow wups my bad, fixed it

Comment: I think I've messed up, I have it set up with this part of the code and all of the ascii conversion is in one file, and the discord parts are in another, so I altered your code a little to make it work, but it hasn't, instead of sending the strings one at a time I have it appending them to a list, then at the end it returns the list and that function is called by the main code. The problem I have is that the outputted characters in the Discord chat aren't an image, theres not a lot I can do to figure out why, as they're all jumbled up, but I'll keep looking, any help is great.

Comment: @Jake my guess is that the lines of your image are longer than the maximum amount of characters that fit on a line on your monitor in discord?

Comment: That is possible but I believe its to do with discord formatting, eg you can type *test* and it will put it in bold, so I think that all the asterisks are formatting things and so not showing. 

Edit: Yes I think its to do with formatting so I will just put it in ``` as this stops the formatting, although I must have broken it somewhere else because now its not outputting anything.

Comment: You *can* put it in a codeblock  but that won't look as good if it sends in multiple parts as they won't be connected together anymore. What you could do is escape the markdown syntax (replace `*` with `\*`, etc) but this drastically lowers the amount of characters you can send so be aware of that. It'll require more messages. I'd honestly suggest lowering the resolution of the ascii image so that it has fewer characters.

Comment: You're probably right as this is getting more and more difficult to do whilst making it look good, the resolution is taken in when you run it so as long as its less than 40x40 I guess it'll work, thanks.